# ManagedPipelineHandler - IIS 8.5 intermittent error 500

Tags: iis, 500-error

on our production server we suddenly have intermittent error 500, checking the failed request log I can see the following, but it doesn't help me too much, I can't see where the problem is. Is it something related to cache? Or cookies?

```
-NOTIFY_MODULE_START 


ModuleName
ManagedPipelineHandler 

Notification
EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER 

fIsPostNotification
false 

-AspNetPipelineEnter 


ConnID
0 

Context ID
{80000472-0401-5100-B63F-84710C7967BB} 

Data1
System.Web.ImplicitAsyncPreloadModule 

-AspNetPipelineLeave 


ConnID
0 

Context ID
{80000472-0401-5100-B63F-84710C7967BB} 

Data1
System.Web.ImplicitAsyncPreloadModule 

-AspNetHttpHandlerEnter 


ConnID
0 

Context ID
{80000472-0401-5100-B63F-84710C7967BB} 

-GENERAL_SET_RESPONSE_HEADER 


HeaderName
X-AspNetMvc-Version 

HeaderValue
4.0 

Replace
false 

-GENERAL_SET_RESPONSE_HEADER 


HeaderName
Cache-Control 

HeaderValue
private 

Replace
true 

-GENERAL_SET_RESPONSE_HEADER 


HeaderName
X-AspNet-Version 

HeaderValue
4.0.30319 

Replace
true 

-MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS 


ModuleName
ManagedPipelineHandler 

Notification
EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER 

HttpStatus
500 

HttpReason
Internal Server Error 

HttpSubStatus
0 

ErrorCode
The operation completed successfully.
(0x0) 

ConfigExceptionInfo

-NOTIFY_MODULE_END 


ModuleName
ManagedPipelineHandler 

Notification
EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER 

fIsPostNotificationEvent
false 

NotificationStatus
NOTIFICATION_CONTINUE
```

Comment: What about telling us your configuration?

Comment: windows server 2012, iis 8.5, web app uses ASP.net 4.5, MVC 4.0

Comment: We are seeing this too.   Would be great if someone from Microsoft could chime in just about now.

Comment: I've got the same problem.  Immensely frustrating that there's no clues as to the cause.